# Hibernate Criteria API - Ordering with asc/desc on Field with multiple columns broken

Tags: hibernate, sql-order-by, criteria-api

When doing a select with order by on a hibernate field which is persisted on the db with two columns, the ordering is broken because asc and desc doesn't work properly.

Example field definition:

```
@Columns(columns = {@Column(name = "currency"), @Column(name = "value")})
private BigMoney price;
```

When doing a select with order by on this field, the criteria api creates a hql like this:

```
select * from SOMETABLE order by price desc
```

At some point, hibernate translates the hql into sql which looks like this:

```
select * from SOMETABLE order by currency, value desc
```

This is wrong. It should be

```
select * from SOMETABLE order by currency desc, value desc
```

How can this be bypassed? The problem seems to be in org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect::renderOrderByElement:

```
public String renderOrderByElement(String expression, String collation, String order, NullPrecedence nulls) {
    final StringBuilder orderByElement = new StringBuilder( expression );
    if ( collation != null ) {
        orderByElement.append( " " ).append( collation );
    }
    if ( order != null ) {
        orderByElement.append( " " ).append( order );
    }
    if ( nulls != NullPrecedence.NONE ) {
        orderByElement.append( " nulls " ).append( nulls.name().toLowerCase( Locale.ROOT ) );
    }
    return orderByElement.toString();
}
```

There, it expected one order by expression. But in my case, it passes two concatenated expressions.

Comment: Someone had this problem years ago but still now answer: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=1043335&view=next  -  possibly a bug?